# Invalid Column Name though it's there!

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to print out Tables from the DB that have the EntityId column equals to DataclassId column here is the code

```
    public void getRootTables_checkSP()
    {
        string connect = "Data Source= EUADEVS06\\SS2008;Initial Catalog=TacOps_4_0_0_4_test;integrated security=SSPI; persist security info=False;Trusted_Connection=Yes";
        SqlDataReader rootTables_List = null;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connect);
        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand s_cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM sys.Tables WHERE EntityId = DataclassId", conn);
        rootTables_List = s_cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (rootTables_List.Read())
        {
            string test = rootTables_List[0].ToString();
            Console.WriteLine("ROOT TABLES ARE {0}", test);
        }
        rootTables_List.Close();
        conn.Close();
    }
```

but it keeps saying that these columns are invalid though when I printed out all the columns in the DB "syscolumns" they were there...

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting such an error?

**EDIT**

What I really want is to query the db TacOps_4_0_0_4_test not the system. I just realized that

**EDIT 2**

Here is an example of the Tables in my DB

```
Table_1
ID  Sequence    Type    Heigh  Weight   EntityId    DataclassId
0   1           s       1.4     2.5     42-2c-Qi    42-2c-Qi
1   2           s       2.4     2.5     zh-km-xd    zh-km-xd
2   3           s       3.4     2.5     8n-tr-l7    8n-tr-l7

Table_2
ID  Data    Person    EntityId    DataclassId
0   1        Dave     58-zj-4o    41-2c-Q7
1   2        Sara     99-op-t6    oy-7j-mf
2   3        Silve    75-qy-47    2d-74-ds

Table_3
ID  Name    Genre   EntityId    DataclassId
0   LR      Ac      78-jd-o9    78-jd-o9
1   OI      Dr      4t-jb-qj    4t-jb-qj
2   DH      Do      7j-3e-ol    7j-3e-ol
```

The output should be

```
Table_1
Table_3
```

Comment: What do you mean by "these columns"? What *exactly* is the error message?

Comment: i tried this query >>> SELECT * FROM sys.Tables WHERE EntityId = DataclassId in SQL SERVER 2008 it said Invalid column name. Probably error in query. I never knew any columns in sys.table named "EntityId" - dataclassid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *think* I may understand what you're trying now based on your comment to Frederik's answer

> I tried "syscolumns" just to make sure
>   that the columns do exist. But when I
>   do the query where EntityId =
>   DataclassId it says "Invalid column
>   name

It sounds like EntityId and Dataclassid are columns in a table (or tables) that you have in your database and you want to find the rows from those tables that contain the same value in both those columns??

If that's the case, you are querying sys.Tables incorrectly - you'd need to query the specific tables directly i.e.

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE EntityId = DataClassId
```

Can you clarify?

**Edit:**
You can find all the tables that contain both those columns using this:

```
SELECT t.name
FROM sys.tables t
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.columns c WHERE c.object_id = t.object_id AND c.name='EntityId')
    AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.columns c WHERE c.object_id = t.object_id AND c.name='DataClassId')
```

From this, you could either iterate round each table and run the query to find rows that match on EntityId/DataClassId values - could insert into a temp table and return 1 resultset at the end.

OR, you could create a view to UNION all the tables together and then query that view (would need to update the view each time you added a new table).

OR, you could do some dynamic SQL generation based on the above to generate a SELECT statement on-the-fly to UNION all the tables together.

**Update:**
Here's a generic way to do it in pure TSQL - this way means if new tables are added it will automatically include them:

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @SQL = COALESCE(@SQL + CHAR(10) + 'UNION ALL' + CHAR(10), '') 
    + 'SELECT ''' + REPLACE(QUOTENAME(t.Name), '''', '''''') + ''' AS TableName, COUNT(*) AS RowsMatched FROM ' + QUOTENAME(t.name) 
    + ' WHERE EntityId = DataClassId'
FROM sys.tables t
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.columns c WHERE c.object_id = t.object_id AND c.name='EntityId')
    AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.columns c WHERE c.object_id = t.object_id AND c.name='DataClassId')

SET @SQL = 'SELECT x.TableName, x.RowsMatched FROM (' + @SQL + ') x WHERE x.RowsMatched > 0 ORDER BY x.TableName'
EXECUTE(@SQL)
```

If you don't need it to be dynamic, change the above EXECUTE to a PRINT to see the SQL it generates, and then create a view from it. You can then SELECT from that view.

Of course, you could either loop round each table 1 by 1 as you are trying.

Comment: true that's what I want but I want this for all tables not only one

Comment: @AdaTheDev: Actually I know all the tables have EntityId and DataclassId. Can't I  directly query them for equal values?

Comment: @Reda - yep, if you know they all have them. If you don't want to define a view up front, but instead want to dynamically look at each table that exists at execution time, then you could scrap the WHERE clause on sys.tables to just return all tables

Comment: I don't want all tables I want all tables that have the same values under EntityId and DataclassId. Can you tell me how the condition would look like for this query (i.e instead of the last WHERE clause in your code)

Comment: @ AdaTheDev: Check my Answer. I tried what you first suggested but I didn't get the correct output

Comment: @AdaTheDev-Update: You mean I put this inside the first while loop?

Comment: I actually no nothing of the TSQL. Is there another method for this? Because I still need to do some test on the root tables after I get them

Comment: @Reda - I mean, only have 1 SqlCommand + SqlDataReader. Execute something like what I've put in my update, which will return in one call a list of all the tables with the corresponding row count. So you wouldn't need nested loops as you get all the data in one go.

Comment: @AdaTheDev: Thx it works :D finally I can move on. But do you know how can I skip the Null tables? I noticed that it also takes the tables with null values. Can you help me out with that?

Comment: @Reda - Pls see I've updated the SQL (added in "REPLACE") to guard against any single quotes in table names (unlikely but possible). The [] are added by the QUOTENAME function call that wraps "t.Name" - removing that function call would remove the square brackets.

Comment: @AdaTheDev: Actually I went more thoroughly in the list and discovered that the query doesn't work as it suppose to. There were some tables retrieved that have different EntityId and DataclassId... Is there other way than TSQL? I need to know how I'm querying

Comment: @Reda - You really need to give an exact, specific example (example tables with example rows) and clarify what you want to be returned. Otherwise I'm just trying to work it out in the dark

Comment: ok I'll add some in my original post soon. your help is greatly appreciated

Comment: @Reda - please see I've updated the SQL in the "Update" section of my answer - it will now only return records for the tables that do having matching rows on those 2 fields. Tables with no matches, will not be returned.

Comment: @AdaTheDev: I posted another similar post on this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785058/query-to-select-tables-with-similar-column-values)

Comment: @AdaTheDev: I went through all the generated list and compared it with the DB Tables, here is what I came up with: Your query selects exactly the opposite of what I needed (i.e. Tables with different EntityId/DataclassId columns. I fixed that easily by modifying the WHERE clause. I also noticed that the generated list also contains empty tables (with Null in all their rows) how can I filter these?

Comment: @Reda - I've updated the final WHERE clause, just before the execute (see updated SQL). Basically: "WHERE x.RowsMatched > 0" instead of "WHERE x.RowsMatched = 0". Quick test with 4 tables, 1 with matching rows in, 1 without matching rows, 1 with no rows in, and 1 with rows that only have NULLs in each of those columns - that behaves as expected, only returning the 1 table that does have matches in.

Comment: Yes that's it :D My struggle (and yours) is finally over. Thx a lot AdaTheDev

Comment: No problem. Glad we got there in the end!

Answer (score 6):

EntityId and DataclassId are indeed no columns that exists in the sys.tables.

You're selecting data from sys.tables, there's no notion of syscolumns in your query, so i do not know why you're mentionning 'syscolumns' in your explanation ?

Comment: +1 - neither of those columns exist in sys.tables (or syscolumns/sys.columns)

Comment: I tried "syscolumns" just to make sure that the columns do exist. But when I do the query where EntityId = DataclassId it says "Invalid column name"

Comment: Which is logical ...  those columns do not exist in sys.tables.

Comment: They don't exists in syscolumns either, so i don't know from where you're getting those ...

Comment: oh I get it! Sorry. I wanna query the columns in my connect string db I thought sys.tables gets me the tables for it

Comment: they are in every table in the TacOps_4_0_0_4_test db

Answer (score 1):

Based on all the comments, i think what you might be trying to find is ALL tables in your database that have both EntityID and DataClassID columns.

I know...its a pretty WILD guess but dont blame me for trying!! :-)

If my shot in the pretty awesome darkness that is your question is correct, try this out:

```
SELECT tabs.name 
FROM sys.tables tabs INNER JOIN sys.columns cols
ON tabs.object_id = cols.object_id
AND cols.name IN ('EntityId', 'DataClassId')
```

Comment: almost! I wanna find only tables that have the column EntityId equal to DataclassId

Comment: @Reda - what exactly do you mean by "column EntityId equal to DataclassId" ? Are columns equal if they have the same datatypes? Are columns equal if they have similar datatypes eg an int and a smallint are similar? What is your criteria for equating columns?

Comment: @In Sane: I mean they have the same values (i.e. Col_1 has 3 and Col_2 has 3 as well)

Comment: @Reda - i dont think that there is any way to do that using these sys views that we are talking about. In order to match data, you dont have a choice but to query the actual tables that have the data.Eg : If there is a table X with EntityId  and DataclassId columns. Now, table X may have some rows that may have entityId and DataclassId same and some rows different. The only way you can know is by doing a Select count(*) from X where EntityId = DataClassId.

Comment: In my DB if a table has one row with the same EntityId and DataclassId then all rows will have the same. As for the query you wrote I want X to stand for all the tables in my DB. How do I iterate through them using c# code? and btw it's not a must to use sys views I was just trying.. any other solution is fine by me

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you do a `sp_help 'sys.Tables'` in SQL Management Studio you'll see that, indeed, those columns are not part of sys.Tables...